# jquery, как отключить autofield в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

у меня есть форма, и я хочу в ней отключить автозаполнение.

я перепробовал много вариантов, типо таких как

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Использова как и в `<form autocomplete="off">` так и для input, ничего не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

серавно появляется список и автозаполнение срабатывает. Подскажите, как от него избавиться?

```
<form id="request-help-step1-form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Media type<span class="required">*</span></label><br>
            <div class="device-type-section">
                <input id="dt1" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media" checked>
                <label for="dt1" class="device-type-btn">PC/Mac</label>

                <input id="dt2" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Hard Disk Drive">
                <label for="dt2" class="device-type-btn">HDD</label>

                <input id="dt3" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SSD - Solid State Drive">
                <label for="dt3" class="device-type-btn">SSD</label>

                <input id="dt4" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
                <label for="dt4" class="device-type-btn">Flash</label>

                <input id="dt5" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
                <label for="dt5" class="device-type-btn">SD</label>

                <input id="dt6" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="RAID Server Drive(s)">
                <label for="dt6" class="device-type-btn">RAID</label>

                <input id="dt7" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Mobile Phone">
                <label for="dt7" class="device-type-btn">Mobile</label>

                <input id="dt8" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media">
                <label for="dt8" class="device-type-btn">Other</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 additional-info">
                <div class="col-md-12 title">
                    Additional Information
                </div>
                <div class="ai-content">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Model<br>
                            <input type="text" name="deviceModel" class="deviceModel" value="" size="40"
                                   aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Model">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Serial<br>
                            <input type="text" name="deviceSerial" class="deviceSerial" value="" size="40"
                                   aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Serial">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Organization Name<br>
                            <input type="text" name="companyName" class="companyName" value="" placeholder="Company">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="statedSource">How did u hear about us?<br>
                            <select name="statedSource" class="statedSource">
                                <option value="">How did u hear about us?</option>
                                    <option value="tested">tested</option>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-12 failure-details">
            <label>Failure Circumstances and Required Data<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <textarea maxlength="10000" name="problemDetails" class="problemDetails" rows="10" aria-invalid="false"
                          placeholder="Problem Details"></textarea>
            </label>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label data-tooltip="">First Name<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstName'] ?>"
                       size="40" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="John">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label data-tooltip="">Last Name<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" class="lastName" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastName'] ?>" size="40"
                       aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Doe">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label data-tooltip="">Email<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?>" size="40"
                       aria-invalid="false" placeholder="jdoe@email.com">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label data-tooltip="">Phone<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="phone1" class="phone1" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone1'] ?>" size="40"
                       aria-invalid="false" placeholder="(201) 555 5555">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label data-tooltip="">Shipping Address<span class="required">*</span><br>
                <input id="autocomplete" type="text" name="addressZip" class="addressZip"
                       value="<?php echo $_POST['addressZip'] ?>" size="40" aria-invalid="false"
                       placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()">
            </label>

            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="street_number" value="<?=$_POST['street_number'] ?>" id="street_number">
            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="route" value="<?=$_POST['route'] ?>" id="route" />
            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="city" value="<?=$_POST['city'] ?>" id="locality"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="state" value="<?=$_POST['state'] ?>" id="administrative_area_level_1"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="zipCode" value="<?=$_POST['zipCode'] ?>" id="postal_code"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="field" name="country" value="<?=$_POST['country'] ?>" id="country"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="height:30px;"></div>
        <div id="alert-box" class="col-md-12" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 buttons_row">
            <input type="button" value="Submit a case" class="submit-btn next-step">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

также я пытался использовать jQuery и `disableAutoFill()`, но оно также не помогало

Comment: Какой у вас браузер? И еще лучше приложите ваш кусок кода с формой

Comment: я использую google chrome.